# Is set-option -g prefix enough to change tmux's prefix key

Tags: configuration, tmux

In order to change tmux's prefix key from `Ctrl-b` to `Ctrl-a` it seems to be enough to include the statement `set-option -g prefix C-a` in tmux's configuation file (e.g. `~/.tmux.conf`). But Arch's Wiki article about [tmux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux)  suggests the following sequence of statements to achieve the same effect:

> For example, the default prefix binding of Ctrl-b can be changed to
>   Ctrl-a by adding the following commands in your configuration file:
>
> ```
> unbind C-b
> set -g prefix C-a
> bind C-a send-prefix
> ```

So which approach is the right one?